# Searching in DataTables with column priority

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I'm trying to do a search using DataTables and everything is fine, but I have a problem that I haven't been able to solve. Say I have a table like so:

```
NAME |   TAGS
----------------
Tom  | qwe, mark
Mark | dfg, uio
```

When I do a search for "mark" the order remains as shown above, but I want to somehow give the NAME column a higher priority so when I search for "mark" the order would be reversed:

```
NAME |   TAGS
----------------
Mark | dfg, uio
Tom  | qwe, mark
```

Is there any way to set search priorities to columns? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my workaround with a hidden column:

```
$(function () {
    let i = 0;
    let table_selector = "#myTableId";
    let input_unique_id = "datatables_helper_id";
    let hidden_col_index = document.querySelector(table_selector + " thead tr").childElementCount;

    $(table_selector)
        .find("tr")
        .each(function () {
            let trow = $(this);
            trow.append("<td>" + i + "</td>");
            i += 1;
        });
    let table = $(table_selector).DataTable({
        pageLength: 10,
        columnDefs: [
            {
                targets: [hidden_col_index],
                visible: false,
                searchable: false,
            },
        ],
    });

    $(table_selector + "_filter label input").on("focus", function () {
        this.setAttribute("id", input_unique_id);
    });

    $("body").on("keyup", "#" + input_unique_id, function () {
        table.rows({ search: "applied" }).every(function () {
            if (this.data()[0].startsWith(table.search())) {
                let data = this.data();
                data[hidden_col_index] = 1;
                this.data(data);
            } else {
                let data = this.data();
                data[hidden_col_index] = 2;
                this.data(data);
            }
        });
        table.order([[hidden_col_index, "asc"]]).draw();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no way to do so directly from the datatables (on the client side). I've tried to use a custom filtering algorithm but couldn't make it work.

The only way I ccould think of was to make the datatables **server side** processing and returned the data filtered and ordered the way I want (by priority) from the server. But this also means that I had to manage every datatables event (sort, filter, pagination...) in the server side, maybe not ideal.

If you want to give it a try, take a look at the [server side processing mode](https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/server_side.html).